# Using application.ini for configuring Zend_Application Bootstrap

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-application, zend-app-bootstrap

I have written custom resources for my Zend_Application bootstrap.

In [the manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.theory-of-operation.html#zend.application.theory-of-operation.bootstrap.resource-plugins) the following code is given for loading them:

```
$application = new Zend_Application(APPLICATION_ENV, array(
    'pluginPaths' => array(
        'My_Resource' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/resources/',
    ),
    'resources' => array(
        'FrontController' => array(
            'controllerDirectory' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/controllers',
        ),
    ),
));
```

This however does not make use of the application.ini which I want to use. Is there a possibility to configure this completely from my application.ini?

**My final solution:** (with help of Will's answer):

- create an empty project with zf.sh create project (version 1.9.6)
- make the following class in application/resources/Ftp.php

  ```
  class My_Resource_Ftp extends Zend_Application_Resource_ResourceAbstract 
  {
      protected $_params = array();
      public function init() {
          echo "init invoked";
          return array("hey");
      }
  }
  ```
- The following application.ini

  ```
  [production]
  phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
  phpSettings.display_errors = 0
  includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
  bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
  bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"

  pluginPaths.My_Resource = APPLICATION_PATH "/resources/"
  resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"

  resources.ftp.username = "me"


  [staging : production]

  [testing : production]
  phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
  phpSettings.display_errors = 1

  [development : production]
  phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
  phpSettings.display_errors = 1
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you just have to use the path to your application.ini as the second argument to the constructor, e.g:

```
$application = new Zend_Application(
  APPLICATION_ENV,
  APPLICATION_PATH . '/config/application.ini'
);
```

This is the approach the quick start guide takes: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.quick-start.html

In your .ini file you would then add resource paths like:

```
pluginPaths.My_Resource = APPLICATION_PATH "/resources/"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it does not work. I updated my question with this try and the error.

Comment: Not quite sure from the error message, will try to debug it myself later, but did notice I made a copy/paste error in my .ini file example: there shouldn't be a dot after APPLICATION_PATH in the pluginPaths line - sorry, try it without that.